# Question regarding the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assuming the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem that every sequence $x_n$ has either a convergent subsequence or a divergent subsequence. My question is can both occur?

Comment: that is a misuse of notation. no sequence is *converging* to infinity.

Comment: Every *bounded* divergent sequence has both.

Comment: Every sequence in any topological space has a convergent or a divergent subsequence. No Bolzano theorem needed for that.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Take $x_n=(-1)^n$. Then $\{x_n\}$ is divergent but has $\{x_{2n}\}$ as a convergent sub-sequence.

Answer (score 4):

Let the sequence $(a_n)$ defined by
$$a_{n}=1\;\text{if $n$ is odd}\quad;\quad a_{n}=n\;\text{if $n$ is even}$$
so $(a_{2n+1})$ is a convergent subsequence and $(a_{2n})$ is a divergent subsequence.